# Django ArrayField. How to save nested array of time through django admin?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin, django-orm

I already asked this question several months ago.

Question is stupid, but i cant find solution. What a valid format for saving nested array of time from simple form text field?

I have ArrayField like this:

```
schedule = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            ArrayField(
                models.TimeField(null=True),
            ),
            size=2,
            null=True,
        ),
        size=7,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

When i am trying to save it from django admin like:

```
((09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 9:00), (9:00, 9:00), (9:00, 9:00))
```

I'm getting errors

```
Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 1 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 2 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 3 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 4 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 5 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 6 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 7 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 8 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 9 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 10 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 11 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 12 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 13 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
```

I already tried some other formats like: [["09:00", "09:00"]] or (('09:00', '09:00')) or just plain text like "09:00", "09:00" but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `schedule` field is a 3-dimensions array, but you are passing a 2-dimensions array.

The `schedule` field definition should be:

```
schedule = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.TimeField(null=True),
        size=2,
        null=True,
    ),
    size=7,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)
```

Also, the default Django widget does not support nested arrays. You will have to create your own widget.

Comment: This is right notice, but after changings in models.py I still can't save array and getting same error messages.

Comment: Thinking a bit further, it seems reasonable that django default form fields and/or widgets do not support nested arrays. You would have to create your own formfield/widget to handle your `schedule` field. Can you tell me your version of Django? I will try to write such widget to complete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

concluding @antoine-pinsard answer, I will add, that it's impossible to save field like Array(Array(SomeSimpleField)) - because django's `from django.contrib.postgres.forms import SimpleArrayField`  forms doesn't allow it.
So the solution is simple - I've created own root ArrayField and specified arrays' delimiter as `;`:

```py
class RootArrayField(ArrayField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super().formfield(
            delimiter=";",
            **kwargs,
        )

...

class CustomModel(models.Model):
    some_field = RootArrayField(
        ArrayField(models.DecimalField(...)),
        ...
    )
```

And now I'm able to fill the field like: `12.33, 43,12; 334.54, 12.4`